# Jquery/JqGrid - Grid paging controls are cut off when a grid contains only a single column

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I have a page which contains a dynamically generated grid, where a user can select which columns are shown. There can be a reasonable amount of data rows, so the grid has paging enabled.

The works fine in most circumstances, except when there is only a single column displayed. In this case, the paging control is cut off at about the halfway mark, making it impossible to page.

I've created two simple grids in JSFiddle to illustrate - http://jsfiddle.net/2wj2A/ . The top grid with two cols looks as expected, whereas the bottom grid with a single column shows the cut off problem.

Is there any way to make the grid take the paging control into account when it shrinks to fit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not clear to me exactly how your application is rendering the grid. That said, if you can detect when only one column is displayed, you could add code to ensure that the grid (and that single column) is at least a certain minimum width. Then you just need to make the minimum value wide enough that the pager controls are not truncated.

Does that help?

Comment: I ended up doing what you suggested, and manually defining the width of the column to be large enough when there was only a single column on the grid. It felt a little hacky, but is probably the best way.

Comment: Right, the jqGrid itself should really enforce the minimum width in this case. Maybe a bug should be filed. In any case, I'm glad you were able to work around the problem.